# jQuery Mobile keeps style on next page

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

My main page uses jQuery Mobile styling and when I click a link to go to another page (print.php) it keeps styling my print.php with jQuery Mobile although I have not added this style to this page header.

Page index.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"> 
<!--This button goes to print.php--> 
<a class="btn" href="print.php?id=1">
```

Page print.php:

```
<!-- I have also try to remove jQuery Mobile even if it's not added in the header-->
 <div class="container"  data-enhance="false">
```

However, when I refreshed the page it works.

Are you able to help me?

Thank you

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the jQM docs:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/

By default pages are loaded into the current DOM via AJAX. To defeat this add

```
data-ajax="false"
```

to your link.

Comment: Wow never thought of this, thank you very much! The link explains very well why. You have solved my problem!